# Resume from sleep and retain state

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hybrid-sleep

Up until I recently reinstalled a new copy of windows 10 I could put my PC into sleep, turn off the power at the mains but then I could turn the power on again, restart my PC and it would resume in the same state as if I hadn't turned off the power. Now; after a clean install, when I turn off at the mains and on again; during sleep, my state is not retained. Unsure how I had this feature before but is there anyway I can get this feature back?

Comment: Did you update your power drivers? Fresh install might have changed these. Did you check your Windows Power Settings?  May sure Suspend is ON and (at least until you check) Hybrid Sleep and Hibernation are both OFF.

Comment: ty you put me onto the right track ... first I tried to mess around with hybrid sleep but couldn't find it, so then I enabled Hibernation and it was still missing ... so then I thought my bios might be at fault but it's a bit old so no S3 options ... but whilst I was in the bios I updated it to the latest, then after a reboot I checked if hybrid sleep was available and it was now and it was set to ON ... so I launch a browser, selected sleep, the pc then went into sleep mode, I then turned off the power, restarted the pc and it worked the browser was still loaded on the page I left it :) .. ty

Comment: So is this an answer I should post for you?

Answer (score 0):

What you state shows a misunderstanding of [*Sleep*, as opposed to *Hibernation*](https://www.howtogeek.com/102897/whats-the-difference-between-sleep-and-hibernate-in-windows/): " I could put my PC into sleep, **turn off the power at the mains** but then I could turn the power on again, restart my PC and it would resume in the same state as if I hadn't turned off the power."

*Hibernation* serializes (stores) the state of the system to a drive, whether HDD or SDD, in a file called *hiberfil.sys*.  All work on the machine is saved, e.g. open documents, at the place you left off, browser open to the web page(s) you were viewing. All this information is kept in *hiberfil.sys* so you can return to where you were in a few seconds after starting.

*Sleep* puts the PC into a low-power state, requiring continuous power, whether from laptop battery or the AC mains. The PC *appears* to be shut down, but is running at a low rate, so it can recognize a key press and resume immediately. *Nothing is stored to disk,* and if the power is abruptly removed, there is the possibility of disk corruption.

If you wish to enable hibernation, in a CMD prompt as Administrator, run the following:

```
  powercfg -h on
```

If you want a batch file to both re-enable hibernation and then to actually hibernate, put the following into the script:

```
  powercfg -h on
  shutdown /h
```

Comment: Yes totally understand hibernation vs sleep but the option I have always selected was sleep ... and the power light flashes when in sleep mode. So still unsure how the sleep option restored my state after power cycle.

Comment: It could not possibly have, if there were no internal battery supercapacitor... or, if you waited, and *it went from Sleep to Hibernation after a fixed time*. See Power Options for that timeout.

Comment: It doesn't help that there is now an apparently hidden "hybrid sleep" mode which seems to be the default (at least it was for me) and acts almost like hibernation.